# A few chairs or few chairs?

Tags: grammar, articles

I was wondering why we use the article "a" before few? For example, why we say *a few chairs* instead of *few chairs*? Is it similar to the word "a lot"? We say *a lot of chairs* instead of *lot of chairs*.

Comment: They mean different things.

Comment: 'a few' and 'a lot of' are compound quantifiers. 'Some' can sometimes be switched for 'a few', and 'many' can often be switched for 'a lot of'.  [Larry Zwier](http://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/grammar-practice-activities/2015/12/compound-quantifiers-alternatives-to-much-and-many) has a good introduction. [ProfessorCA.wordpress.com/grammar](https://professorca.wordpress.com/grammar-2/determiners/e-quantifiers-a-few-a-little-much-many-a-lot-of-most-some-any-enough/) lists some quantifiers (but misinterprets them as a subset of adjectives).

Comment: The important term here is _negative_. The difference between _few_ and _a few_ is negation. They can both refer to the same number, but _few_ is a negative trigger and licenses negative polarity items like _ever_, while _a few_ isn't negative, just diminutive. Thus _Few people ever saw it_, but not *_A few people ever saw it._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“A few chairs” would mean some chairs, not many but not none. The quantity is notable for being non-zero.

“Few chairs” would mean not as many chairs as you expected, or as you needed.  The quantity is notable for being low.

“A few people” have been to the Moon.

“Few people” do not know a few people have been to the Moon.

Comment: Hello Michael. The question is a duplicate, fully answered at the original (barring supporting quotes, not regarded as nigh-on essential in the early days of ELU.